# using preload.js and create.js load an image?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I am following up with a game development tutorial for windows 8 here http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-simple-windows-8-game-with-javascript-game-basics-createjseaseljs/.
The tutorial probably needs updating since at some point i had to add in createJS before using PreloadJS.

example:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
preload = new createjs.PreloadJS();
```

or else the debugging throws errors.

However the program breaks when bgImage is initialised. Any suggestive codes i can use?

```
bgImage = preload.getResult("screenImage").Result;
bgBitmap = new Bitmap(bgImage);
bgBitmap.scale_X = SCALE_X;
bgImage.scale_Y = SCALE_Y;
stage.addChild(bgBitmap);
stage.update();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you are using correct syntax.

```
var bgImage = preload.getResult("screenImage").result;
var bgBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(bgImage);
stage.addChild(bgBitmap);
```

Also what is the bug you are getting?
Here is a quick example that should help.

```
function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");

        //check to see if we are running in a browser with touch support
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
        createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage);

        images = images || {};
        var manifest = [
            {src:"image.jpg", id:"image"}
        ]

        loader = new createjs.PreloadJS(false);
        loader.onFileLoad = handleFileLoad;
        loader.onComplete = handleComplete;
        loader.loadManifest(manifest);
    }

    function handleFileLoad(o) {
    //You could store all your images in object to call them easily.  
    if (o.type == "image") {
            images[o.id] = o.result;
        }
    }

    function handleComplete(event) {
        var bg = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("image").result);
        //OR samething
        //var bg = new createjs.Bitmap(images['image']);
        stage.addChild(bg);
    }

    function tick() {
        stage.update();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note that PreloadJS 0.3.0 (February 2013) has a slightly different API to help support the new event model. Specifically, the getResult method and fileload event payload have changed. See the documentation for more details.